# Reduce boot time for windows update on server

Tags: windows, boot, windows-update, windows-server-2008

I have a server at home which runs Windows server 2008 R2. (I suppose this would work for any OS version. You do not have to keep this in mind while answering.) I seldomly install windows updates on it because the boot times are long, and I don't want to have the services I run on it be offline for too long.

If I normally reboot the server without windows updates, it takes some time, but its acceptable. But if I have to install, say... 100 windows updates, the boot time can be extended quite a bit.

Is there a way to minimize the boot time? I've considered running the server inside a Hyper-V but then the hyper-v server would still need to be updated and rebooted once in a while, which defeats the purpose. Upgrading the server's hardware is also out of the question.

Rebooting more frequently with less updates would of course work, but thats not what I want to know here.

Comment: Use a ssd as system drive

Comment: @Dan He said: "Upgrading the server's hardware is also out of the question." Additionally, the whole installation would have to be changed...

Comment: For speed, yup, I'd boot it from SSD. For 'convenience & downtime' I'd just do it overnight. All the machines here are generally set to do housekeeping tasks when that particular user is not going to be needing the machine - which varies per user, but I have about 5 hrs overnight when no-one is likely to be using the network.

Comment: I assumed he does not want to upgrade the server hardware like in the motherboard; If there was a magical solution to apply 100 windows updates fast, I'd like to know it. A ssd is really cheap these days.

Comment: @Dan: And why would you assume that? He said upgrading is out of the question. The only thing you should assume is upgrading is out of the question. This is very normal in rented servers for example, you have no access to the hardware and cannot change anything.

Comment: Maybe he is not aware that a 80 bucks ssd (if the motherboard accepts sata) will improve thing 10 times speed-wise. On topic: You can disable restore points to lower the disk writes involved, but you will no longer be able, in case of a sistem going south, to revert to a known working state. Also defragmenting the system disk.

Comment: Of course I am aware. As I pointed out, any hardware, SSD included is out of the question to be upgraded. The machine does not have enough storage space to host more than one harddrive and I have too much data on it, so it would need to be a big SSD which means that it will cost a lot of money to simply upgrade that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a proper answer for this. 2008 R2 had its latest service pack four years ago. Windows Update is notoriously inefficient.. Cleaning up your updates folder might make it slightly faster:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2014/05/13/how-to-clean-up-the-winsxs-directory-and-free-up-disk-space-on-windows-server-2008-r2-with-new-update.aspx

1) check if KB2852386 is installed. If not, download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42739
2) turn on Desktop Experience via the Add Features Wizard -> requires reboot!
3) run Windows Cleanup and select Windows Update Cleanup

I tried these steps and they shaved off some time but it's still slow. erver 2012 is a lot faster in my experience.

Comment: Interesting, but will it also speed up booting/installing windows updates, or is it only to clean up/free disk space? And how much speed increase does it gives? Say normal boot time is 20 minutes, with 100 windows updates, its 45 minutes.

Comment: Wow it actually takes 45 minutes? I think the last 2008 r2 I rebooted took less than 10 minutes and it had plenty of updates to install. And yes it should speed up booting as well, Windows Update will check and manipulate files in the Winsxs folder while "Configuring updates".

Comment: Yeah, its an older machine.